# Reduce number of hours of sundays if present between the dates

Tags: mongodb

I'm taking difference of two dates, In that i want to deduct hours of number of sundays present in between.
for example,

```
db.collections.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      waitTime: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: ISODate("2023-08-10T10:24:51.303Z"),
          endDate: ISODate("2023-08-30T10:24:51.303Z"),
          unit: "hour"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Exoecting o/p,

{
waitime : 480 hours
exceptSundays : 408 hours
}

I'm a newbie to mongodb with having basic skills,
Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you

Comment: How is 408 calculated? can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Reduced number hours of sundays occured b/w two dates. ie 3 sundays (480 -72)

Comment: why 3 sunday periods are not 3 * 7 days * 24 hours = 504 hours?

Comment: need to exclude hours of sundays from the calculated waittime. for example if the selected date is between 10-Aug-23 and 20-Aug-23 , waittime will be calculate from $datediff  , from this the sunday hours should be removed. Because sunday is holiday.

Comment: What about other holidays, e.g. Independence Day?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute `$dateDiff` again with `unit: "week"`. Compute the diff using `$subtract` and perform further maths.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      startDate: {
        $min: [
          "$startDate",
          "$endDate"
        ]
      },
      endDate: {
        $max: [
          "$startDate",
          "$endDate"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      waitTime: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$startDate",
          endDate: "$endDate",
          unit: "hour"
        }
      },
      diffWeeks: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$startDate",
          endDate: "$endDate",
          unit: "week"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      waitTime: 1,
      exceptSundays: {
        "$subtract": [
          "$waitTime",
          {
            "$multiply": [
              "$diffWeeks",
              24
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PMjAMhy_fMT)

Comment: This fails if the range passes New Year

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This makes sense. Changed to use `$dateDiff` to compute week diff and added extra safeguard for startDate > endDate