# Subtract Sunday time between the dates

Tags: mongodb

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071775/reduce-number-of-hours-of-sundays-if-present-between-the-dates).

case 1 : if the end date itself is Sunday.[like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_JGR8amXThs), Then the wait time would be zero.

In this case i want only the wait time

case 2 :  if the end date is Monday.[like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iFckxxZ56ge).
In this case i want wait time and Sunday excluded hours.

I'm not able to get values when endDate is within one week.
If the end date is Sunday it should include to the wait time. else it should count to Sunday hours.

correct me if my effort to make this problem understandble is not up to mark.

Any help would be appreciated.

case 1 : if the endDate is Sunday then it should count Sunday to wait hours.

case 2 : if endDate is not sunday then it should exclude Sunday from wait time.